# Is there a way to edit a Google Base Feed?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-base

I just generated an XML google feed from a shopping cart system.  I uploaded it to google and I can't find a way of editing it without going via XML. Is there a facility for editing the file without having to deal with large hunks of XML?  Can you redownload the file as an Excel file, which is much easier to edit?

Answer (score 0):

what shopping cart system are you using?

Before you upload it to google you can open the file and modify it. if it a txt format you can open it in excel, make sure to save it as a txt file
https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160569?hl=en

Comment: Sorry, but I was looking for something easier to work with than streams of long xml verbiage.